# Measure the exact amount of battery usage within a period of time

Tags: battery, battery-history

I'm checking the effectiveness of using different cpu governors for my android phone under different conditions; The problem is that I can't be sure of the amount of battery usage for each configurations with a period of time, say for 1 hour;(so that I compare them)

Is there any way or any app that can tell how much battery was used during the for example last hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) for something like this! You can make a task to do the following:

- **Context:** run between ?? a.m. and ?? p.m.

  - Check the **Repeat** box and set to every 1 hour
- Add Task
- Pick **File** -> **Write File**
- Give it a title, click the "tag" button and choose **Battery Level**
- I checked "Append" and "Add Newline" as well, but the last would be optional I guess.

This will make your phone write the current battery level to a file that you create once each hour. If you're creative with the "Text" field, you could even have it record the time and date as well (See Examples in screenshots).

[image: Context: Time (Repeat)] ->
[image: Add Task: Write File] ->
[image: Battery Log: Setup recording]

Comment: thanks for your replay;
ok; I did it and it works; but can we have battery level with more precision? something like 87.126%

Comment: I don't believe so. From what I know, the percentage is only reported from the system as an integer, so the software itself has no way of reporting tenths/hundredths/thousandths of a percent. I have no references for this though and couldn't find any relevant material, I'd love if someone found some substantial documentation on this.